# Durandal: Manually remove view from DOM

Tags: dom, durandal, single-page-application, detach, durandal-2.0

i am creating a single page application using HotTowel SPA, which uses Durandal 2.0

I have two views, named Dashboard and Settings.

When i load the website, the Dashboard view gets loaded. When i click on Settings, the Dashboard view gets deactivated, and when i click on Dashboard, it gets activated again.

I have a method on my Settings View. When this method is called, i want the Dashboard view to be removed from the DOM. so that when I click on Dashboard again, it has to reload the view (just like it does when you reload the webpage), in stead of just activating it.

So is there a way to detach a view manually?

Comment: Don't really understand the usage, could you explain better what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by removing the view as its interfering with Durandal

Comment: Thanks for replying. 
I want the dashboard page to be reloaded every time i open it (just like when i load the page for the first time). I thought that would be possible if you remove the view from the dom, because durandal says that's what happens when a view get detached. (When you check the durandal Docs, it says that the detached callback will be called "When the associated view is detached from the DOM")

Comment: Basically i want the view to be reloaded every time i activate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can `cacheViews` to false on the composition binding. See about 3/4 down the [Using Composition](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition/)
page.

In the shell.html file (I presume it's the same in HotTowel), there will be a line like:

```
<div class="container-fluid page-host" data-bind="router: { transition:'entrance', cacheViews:false }"></div>
```

Comment: I found that as well. But if i do that, every view always gets detached, and that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: In which case, the same page also says

**Note:** _If you have set cacheViews:true then attached will only be called the first time the view is shown, on the initial bind, since technically the view is only attached once. If you wish to override this behavior, then set alwaysTriggerAttach:true on your composition binding._

Comment: Thank you, that gets pretty close to what I'm looking for. But is there a way to set _alwaysTriggerAttach:true_ only for one view, or only when a certain method gets executed?